# Concurrent Fixed size collection with configurable removal policy

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

Currently I am working on a problem which requires

1. Number of elements to be fixed.
2. Removal previous element if it exceeds the fixed size. Removal policy is fixed currently
3. `LinkedHashMap` is one option but I need collection to be concurrent.
4. Should support functionlity like `BoundedQueue` but the thread which enque it should never be blocked instead old element should get removed and new should get inserted.
5. `PriorityBlockingQueue` with `drainTo` method is valid option but I will have to call it every time before inserting element.

Can you please suggest me a solution. Source code is not required. I want to only know the best way to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Containment baby.

```
public class MyCollection {

  private LinkedBlockingQueue<MyData> lbq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<MyData>();
  public static final int MAX_SIZE = 5;

  public void add(MyData input) {
    lbq.put(input);
    if(lbq > MAX_SIZE) lbq.poll();
  }


  ... any other methods you need. 
}
```

This may not be exactly correct for your needs, but this should get you started in the right direction.  You can use a data structure that exists, wrap it with some custom code (including making it thread safe), and you can get exactly what you need.

A fundamental concept in design, that I think learned from Effective C++, is that containment is preferred over inheritance.  In this case it is the solution.

Comment: This does not look like it can handle simultaneous `add`s.

Comment: As I said:  "This may not be exactly correct for your needs".  I am pretty sure @AmitD knows what he is doing as far as developing software.  The goal of my post was to get him started in the right direction and he can take it from there.  I probably gave too much information, but that was for others who are not as accomplished to gain some insight.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest starting point would be looking at JDKs LinkedBlockingQueue and creating an alternative implementation that differs in how overfilling puts and offers are handled. Since this happens while holding a private lock, you can not override the behaviour in a subclass.